# .htaccess rewriterules and redirections

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For a domain marketplace, I want to rewrite some urls and redirect my old pages (in a directory) to new pages directly.

For "rewrite url", I used these codes:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*\.php)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*\.htm)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*\.html)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*\.shtml)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/whois/$

RewriteRule ^(.*\.*)$ /details.php?domain=$1 [qsa,l]
RewriteRule ^whois/([^/]*)$ /whoisrequest/whois.php?whois=$1 [L]
```

For example `http://mydomain.com/test.com` url rewrite like `http://mydomain.com/details.php?domain=test.com`- It's okey.

**Problem:** But at the same time, for rewriting whois url (`http://mydomain.com/whois/test.com`) or redirecting old pages (like `http://mydomain.com/domains/123/test.com`) to new ones (like `http://mydomain.com/test.com`) rewriting to `…details.php?domain=…`

**How should I handle these rules:**

- If `http://mydomain.com/test.com`, then rewrite `http://mydomain.com/details.php?domain=test.com` (only on main site and include "."[dot] - It can be like anything.anything )
- If `http://mydomain.com/folder1/` or more folders, then “. (dot) is not important’, will not rewrite.
- Besides, redirect 301 `http://mydomain.com/domains/123/test.com` to `http://mydomain.com/test.com`

Comment: I think `RewriteCond` will be only used in the first `RewriteRule`. Add these for each `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. You are matching very generic `.*\..*` pattern in first rule which will make 2nd rule defunct.
2. You are not using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to avoid rewriting for real files/directories.

Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^whois/([^/]+)/?$ /whoisrequest/whois.php?whois=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /details.php?domain=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you very much anubhava! Your intelligent codes work perfect!

Comment: How can I redirect my old pages? Actually my old urls was rewriting urls too. For example I used this code: 
'**RewriteRule ^domains/([a-z0-9]+)/(.*)/? details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]**'
So, 
http://mydomain.com/domains/123/test.com url rewrited like http://mydomain.com/details.php?id=123

But now, I use domain names instead of ids for details page. I want to _redirect 301 http://mydomain.com/domains/123/test.com to http://mydomain.com/test.com_ with my new htaccess codes. 

Thanks

Comment: For this new redirect you can use: `RewriteRule ^domains/[a-z0-9]+/(.+)/?$ /$1 [NC,L,R]`

Comment: Thanks for your helps anubhava. If you accept, I want to make a little payment to you via paypal

Comment: Thank you for the offer but I like to keep my time on SO for helping out fellow developers in the community. I got benefited by using various open source software many times and this is my way of paying it back to the community.

Comment: Thank you very much. Then, I send an linkedin invitation and I want t contac with you. Best regards,